# C++ Removing the second line from a string if it exists

Tags: c++, multiline

So, what I want to do is, if my input text is

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

The progam makes it into

```
Line1

Line3
Line4
```

But if it's

```
Line1

Line2
Line3
```

Nothing gets changed. It stays like that.

How can this be done using modern c++?

EDIT:

```
str.erase(str.find("\n"), str.find("\n", str.find("\n")) - str.find("\n") + 1);
```

this did the job for me, thanks everyone for helping, sorry for asking the question incorrectly

Comment: Find the first newline, find the second newline, and erase all characters between the two. Three lines of code (more with error checking).

Comment: So do I use "str.find_first_of("\n")"?

Comment: that would work, so would `str.find('\n')`, and dont forget these functions take an optional parameter as a place to start searching. This will help in finding the second newline (start the search one character after the first newline).

Comment: Next time that you ask a question, you should include the code that you wrote so far and explain what it does and what you think it should do. If you do that, there will be more people willing to help you. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sorry in this case i didnt even have a point to start

Answer (score -1):

If I don’t misunderstand your question—

```cpp
int main() {
  string str = "Line1\n\nLine3\nLine4\n";
  cout << "INPUT" << endl;
  cout << str << endl << endl;

  size_t firstNewLine = str.find('\n');
  size_t secondNewLine = str.find('\n', firstNewLine + 1);
  if (secondNewLine == string::npos) secondNewLine = str.size();
  if (firstNewLine + 1 != string::npos)
    str.erase(str.begin() + firstNewLine + 1, str.begin() + secondNewLine);
  cout << "OUTPUT" << endl;
  cout << str << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if there is no `\n` in the input string?

Comment: second part of the code modifies `str1` (again) and then prints `str2`

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me out wrong. I had printed the same variable in a hurry.


If there is no newline, then there will be only one line, which means there is no second line, so there is no need to remove anything.

Comment: but your code calls `erase` nevertheless and will cause undefined behavior in case there is none or only one `\n`

Comment: no, this is correct, in my case there will always be more than one ```\n```, thanks for helping

Comment: I was wrong before. largest_prime_is_463035818 pointed my mistake. I sincerely thank him again.